# WordPress block how to access and save options values

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have some values stored in [WordPress Option table](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/options-api/) that I usually manage with get_option/add_option/update_option/delete_option in php

is there any way to retrieve them with javascript in Gutenberg block or even to manage them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the option as a localized javascript variable: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/294321/accessing-plugin-settings-in-gutenberg

```
wp_localize_script('blocks-js', 'locals', array(
  'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page')
));
```

However, I don't think there is currently a way to set options via Gutenberg. I assume it would be a defined [store](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/data/), but I haven't found anything. The documentation here is kind of lacking.

In the meantime, you could set up a [custom REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) endpoint that handles options changes or just a generic ajax call.

Comment: or just do wp_localize_script to do the initial options pull and then use AJAX calls to update/delete/add options